# Azure DevOps sign in

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, devops

One of my team member cannot sign in to azure devops.

1. I'm the administrator and have created an organization
2. I added him to one of the project in DevOps
3. The team member gets an email and when he clicks to join he gets an error on the Microsoft sign in dialog box the error says "This account is not recognized"

He's a valid email. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the screen shot. [image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the member at the org level or project level? Is the right license assigned as well (stakeholder, basic etc)? Can the member go in if you just send them your project link? Are they in the same tenant as you?

Comment: Thank you @KedMardemootoo   Yes I have added them at the org level and at the project level too. Yes, they have the right license (Basic) they get the invite email. They are part of the same org. I haven't tried send them the link of the project (I can get it from the browser) and will let you know.

Comment: Just an update: I tried using one of my outlook email address and that works fine -

Comment: If you can, provide a screenshot of the error. Sometimes an error page's theme/format can provide clues as to where the error is occurring ...

Comment: Here's the screen shot -

Comment: Ah wait this is clearly an issue with the email id/account itself and not devops specifically. It's possible that's something wrong at the tenant level for that account. If you're the tenant admin I'd suggest you look there, else you should contact them and ask them to review the settings/license/failed account migration etc See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/this-username-may-be-incorrect-make-sure-you-typed/3cd334d3-c60f-4fb2-861f-39596359988c for some clues

Comment: I'm the admin in DevOps - and I created his email id on the hosting service (for example : go daddy - teamuser@abc123.com)  I thoroughly checked his Access Level is Basic and we have a free account for up to five users, it's just three. He's added in the Contributors group and valid users too.